# Determine to which class $\left\{\langle M\rangle\Big\vert L(M)\in RE\setminus R \right\}$ belongs

Tags: turing-machines

As stated in title I want to determine to which class

> $$S=\left\{\langle M\rangle\Big\vert L(M)\in RE\setminus R\right\}$$

belongs. I believe that $S\notin RE\cup\text{co}RE$.

1. In order to show that $S\notin RE$ I tried to reduce $\overline{H_{TM}}$ to $S$ using the fact that $\overline{H_{TM}}\notin RE$
2. In order to show that $S\notin \text{co}RE$ I tried to reduce $H_{TM}$ to S using the fact that $H_{TM}\notin \text{co}RE$.

In both cases I got stuck with defining $M'$ and what it should do.

How should I construct the reduction? Thank you!

Comment: Is $S = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in RE \;\backslash R \}$ the language consisting of all Turing Machines whose languages are "Recursively Enumerable" but not "Recursive"?

Comment: @user137481, exactly.

Comment: If you want to pin down where $S$ lies more closely, it is $\Pi^0_3$ complete. It isn't clear whether you need to decide more than whether $S$ is recursive, RE, coRE or none of the above.